# Parse Issue: Type Name Requires a Specifier or Qualifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, parse-error

I keep getting following error for the following code. Can Any one Tell me how to solve this Error.

In .h file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace tesseract {
    class TessBaseAPI;
};
#endif
```

Inside `@interface` abc

```
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract;
uint32_t *pixels;
```

Error line `tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract;`

## Error :

1. Expected Expression
2. Type name requires a specifier or qualifier.

I have set the base SDK to 5.0 and my `Xcode` Version is 4.5. Also I have changed `.m` to `.mm` file extension.

```
CompileC /Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXCard-bfzxfmheqnrlwnfvttodjyxemqxo/Build/Intermediates/XXXX.build/Debug-iphoneos/mBizCard.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewController.o mBizCard/ViewController.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/XXXXXXXX/trunk
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -iquote
```

In file included from ViewController.h:24:5:`error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract;`
    ^

ViewController.h:24:15: `error: expected expression
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract;`
              ^

ViewController.h:24:5: `warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract;`
    ^~~~~~~~~

`1 warning and 2 errors generated.`

Comment: Are you **certain** every source file that imports that `.h` file has the `.mm` file extension?  Please show the complete error line generated by the compiler.

Comment: This is the line which showing error " tesseract::TessBaseAPI *tesseract; ". And for only one viewController i have renamed as ".mm"

Comment: No I'd like to see the whole message generated by the compiler.  I suspect this error is occurring in an Objective-C source file, rather than Objective-C++.

Comment: Ok, i will edit my question and post the whole thing.

Comment: As suspected! `mBizCard/ViewController.m` is the source file being compiled here.

Comment: but i renamed `mBizCard/ViewController.m` to `mBizCard/ViewController.mm' .How can i do for compiling `mBizCard/ViewController.mm file`??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean; `.mm` files should compile correctly.  The issue here is an Objective-C source file importing a header file that uses C++, which it doesn't understand.  Change all your source files from `.m` to `.mm` with no loss of functionality and it will work.

Comment: Change all your source files from `.m` to `.mm ` means, starts from `main.m`, `appdelegate.m`, ..... files you are saying ah ??

Comment: Why not; or you can just do the ones that are causing compilation errors, but I predict that this will spread as C++ classes are referenced more and more in your app.

Comment: Ok, i will try it and update you.

Comment: @user1485749 So, what the results? Did it solve the issue?

Comment: @Shmidt Thanks, Its working fine. File extension `.mm` has to change for all the places, where i have imported the class.

Comment: @user1485749 In my case, all problems were gone when I put all the files in the same folder.